# python use diskspace instead of RAM by no sufficient RAM

Tags: python, linux, windows, memory-management, operating-system

consider the following python code

```
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as fin, \
             open(sys.argv[3], 'w') as fout:
      reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='%s' % sys.argv[4])
      writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, dialect='excel')
      writer.writeheader()
      writer.writerows(reader)
```

lets assume we have a big file about 2GB as input and our system has only 512MB RAM, this may lead to an error `Memory Usage`

Is there a way to let my code use diskspace instead of RAM even if that will make it slow ? or this is a OS issue and should add more Swap for example ?

## update

the code above is only an example

consider this exmaple

```
with io.open(sys.argv[2], 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fin, \
     io.open(sys.argv[3], 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fout:
    rows = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='%s' % sys.argv[4])
    fout.write(json.dumps(list(rows), indent=4))
```

when using `json.dumps` you always need to write the data at once, and if you want to append the file, you must read the file and append the data and write to the file, something like this

```
data = readjson(jsonfile)
data.append(newentry)
jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data))
```

## update 2 using generator (lazy evolution)

I come to this idea but I'm not sure if it makes a difference

```
def gen(list):
    for e in list:
        yield e

with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as fin, \
             open(sys.argv[3], 'w') as fout:
      reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='%s' % sys.argv[4])
      writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, dialect='excel')
      writer.writeheader()
      writer.writerows(gen(reader))

with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as fin, \
     open(sys.argv[3], 'w') as fout:
    rows = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='%s' % sys.argv[4])
    # fout.write(json.dumps(gen(rows), indent=4)) -> cause error <generator object gen at 0x025BDDA0> is not JSON serializable
    fout.write(json.dumps(gen(list(rows)), indent=4))
```

Comment: Jesus, how old is that computer?

Comment: And if you don't want to read a structure into memory all at once, use the language's laziness. You'll need to lookup if Python supports any lazy processing (probably via a stream).

Comment: Just use a loop: `for row in reader: writer.writerow(row)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it is not a computer but a AWS EC2 Instance, i think its type is t2.nano, we also use Heroku free

Comment: @Eltorrooo Ahh, that makes more sense.

Comment: @eryksun actually the function writerows is implemented in that way, unless you mean I add sleep after writing a row? the code above is only an example, so imagine you want to dump the data to json file, check update

Comment: `DictWriter.writerows` builds a list of all the rows, which basically reads the entire file into main memory and uses even more memory than the file size on disk. But there's no need for this. `reader` is an iterator, based on the underlying file `fin`, which is also an iterator, so you can just loop over `reader` and write a row at a time.

Comment: @eryksun sounds good but what about using generator with `writerows` check my last update

Comment: `reader` is already an iterator, so wrapping it in a generator buys you nothing. The built-in `_csv.writer` has a `writewows` method that calls `writerow` on each row in an iterable of rows, where each row is a sequence, so in principle it plays well with an iterator. However,  `DictWriter.writerows` doesn't use a generator to call `_dict_to_list` on each row in a lazy way. Instead it unnecessarily builds the entire list of rows. You can't use this method if memory is an issue. Use `DictWriter.writerow` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when using json.dumps you always need to write the data at once

Not really.  You really should adopt a streaming approach for large data.  In this case, something like:

```
fout.write('[')
for ii, row in enumerate(rows):
    if ii != 0:
        fout.write(',\n')
    json.dump(row, fout, indent=4)
fout.write(']')
```

This way you can write one row at a time, and you also save the overhead of putting all the `rows` into a `list` which you don't need.

Comment: Use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) instead of `json.dumps`.

Comment: @eryksun: Good idea, I've changed that.